# How to load ace editor with requirejs from CDN?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ace-editor

I am trying to load the ace editor from a CDN with requirejs.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HzEb5JXuavbmHkr1bTqI?p=preview) is a plunkr which illustrates my problem. Ace is not defined in the following case:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: { ace: ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.9/ace'] }
})

$('h1').text("loading ace...");
requirejs([ 'ace'], function(ace) {
  $('h1').text("ace loaded.")
  console.log(ace)
  ace.edit('#editor')
  return
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to define ace as a path to the folder that contains `ace.js`
and require "ace/ace"

```js
requirejs.config({
    paths: { ace: ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.9/'] }
})

$('h1').text("loading ace...");
requirejs(['ace/ace'], function(ace) {
    $('h1').text("ace loaded.")
    console.log(ace)
    ace.edit('editor')
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.14/minified/require.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>    
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div id='editor' style="height:200px"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, simple but I didn't think about pointing to a folder in a CDN.

Comment: How can I load an additional theme ? `editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai")` does not work :-/

Comment: How can I load a theme? `editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai")` does not work :-/ [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31211331/719276) is my new question

Comment: @DannyRaufeisen what other way do you want it to work?

Comment: Thought, the entries in `paths` can usually point directly to js-files. This works for jquery as well (see https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-cdn#how-its-set-up)
So why not in this case?

Comment: @arthur.sw did you found an answer? I still cant set themes. It throws HTTP 404 erros.