# How to load ace editor theme from CDN with requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, cdn, ace-editor

I am trying to load an [ace](http://ace.c9.io) theme from a CDN with requirejs.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CqQo6VDr0MyuyBkMIyQ4?p=preview) is a plunkr which illustrates my problem. The theme can not be found in the following case:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: { ace: ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.9/'] }
})

$('h1').text("loading ace...");
requirejs([ 'ace/ace'], function(ace) {
  $('h1').text("ace loaded.")
  console.log(ace)
  editor = ace.edit('editor')
  editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai")
  return
})
```

Note: *I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30888155/719276)  to load ace editor with requirejs from CDN, but it does not explain how can I load an ace theme.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load ace editor with requirejs from CDN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888155/how-to-load-ace-editor-with-requirejs-from-cdn)

Comment: No, I commented on the other question why my problem was different:   
"How can I load a theme? editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai") does not work"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like there is a bug in ace, and one needs to call

```
ace.config.set("packaged", true)
ace.config.set("basePath", require.toUrl("ace"))
```

before `ace.edit` to configure paths.